# Groovy spock test isn't stubbing correctly -- receiving null

Tags: testing, groovy, mocking, spock, stubbing

For some reason (I'm not very good with Spock and am new to mocking & stubbing) I can't get a particular method to stub with what I want.

I've shortened things down a bit, but basically I have a list of books returned from a search. Each book has a `workId`. There may be older or newer editions of the book, but they all have the same `workId` -- If a user chooses, they can grab all those other editions.

### Preface

---

**Class: Edition**

```
class Edition {
    //some strings, ints, and booleans -- information about the edition
}
```

**Class: EditionResults** for grabbing additional editions of a single work

```
class EditionResults {
    List<Edition> editionsList
    String parentWorkId
}
```

**And one final class: BulkEditions** for packaging multiple works (10 books on a search result page)

```
class BulkEditions {
    List<EditionResults> bulkEditions
}
```

---

### This controller is where I'm having trouble

```
@RequestMapping('/api')
class EditionsController {

    @Autowired
    private EditionsService editionsService
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EditionsController)

    @RequestMapping(value = '/bulkeditions', produces = 'application/json')
    ResponseEntity<BulkEditions> getBulkEditions(
        @RequestParam(value = 'workIds') Set<String> workIds
    ) throws Exception
    {
        BulkEditions newBulkEditions = new BulkEditions(bulkEditions: [])
        workIds.each { workId ->
            EditionResults editions = editionsService.searchEditions(workId)
            logger.info "EditionResults {}", editions
            if (editions?.editionsList) {
                newBulkEditions.bulkEditions << editions
            }
        }
        new ResponseEntity<BulkEditions>(newBulkEditions, HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

particularly, i'm having trouble testing the true branch of `editions?.editionsList` -- for some reason I keep receiving `null` for `editions`

---

### Here's what my test looks like (it always passes, but clover coverage is failing)

```
class EditionsControllerSpec extends Specification {

    private final EditionsService editionsService = Mock(EditionsService)
    private static final Set<String> WORK_ID_SET = '12345' as Set<String>
    private static final String SINGULAR_WORK_ID = '12345'

    @Subject
    private final EditionsController controller = new EditionsController(editionsService: editionsService)

    void 'test get bulk editions'() {
        given:
        EditionResults editionResults = Mock(EditionResults)
        Edition edition = GroovyMock(Edition) //it's a java class
        edition.isAvailable >> true
        //edition.bunchOfOtherProps >> randomValues

        editionResults.editionsList >> [edition]
        editionResults.parentWorkId >> SINGULAR_WORK_ID
    
        editionsService.searchEditions(SINGULAR_WORK_ID) >> editionResults

        when:
        ResponseEntity<BulkLocalEditions> response = controller.getBulkEditions(WORK_ID_SET)

        then:
        response
    }
```

### My problem is this part:

```
editionsService.searchEditions(SINGULAR_WORK_ID) >> editionResults
```

I don't understand why I keep getting this back (from my logger)

```
[Test worker] INFO [EditionsController:100] [doCall] EditionResults ***null***
```

My understanding is that `editionsService.searchEditions(SINGULAR_WORK_ID) >> editionResults` is equivalent to saying "When we hit this `searchEditions` method, make its result `editionResults`" -- which we've already populated.... **so how is it null?**

---

I've tried being as detailed and clean as I can with the question, simplifying for brevity, but please let me know if there's any additional info needed -- and of course thanks in advance.

Also worth noting that it actually works on my local and everything comes back correctly -- it's just this clover coverage getting me

Comment: And if you move that line to the `then:` block?

Comment: @tim_yates well *I* feel like an idiot :) thank you so much!

Comment: Don't, that catches everyone out at least twice 

Comment: Do you or @tim_yates want to 'answer' this so it isn't labelled as unanswered and makes it clearer for someone with a similar issue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tim_yates

`editionsService.searchEditions(SINGULAR_WORK_ID) >> editionResults` should have been in my `then` block